# Is it possible to substitute the requestjs module with electron's net module

Tags: node.js, proxy, request, electron

I'm working on an Electron app that heavily uses the Nodejs [request](https://github.com/request/request) module. However I need to add support for proxies. This looks to be built into Electron namely in it's [net](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/net) module.

Net *looks* similar to the request module. Is it possible to substitute it with request? i.e. To replace request completely by net?

Comment: _technically_ it is possible but net module is more lower level so if you need to implement equivalent you may end up lot of reinventing wheels.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @OJKwon. That's a pity. I'd really like to use Electron's built in support for proxies. But my app is based on a pre-existing SDK that uses node's request module.